# Set up columns before importing excel

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I have a large list which when imported, doesn't transfer every column over as the correct type. Is there a way to make the bones of the list before importing an excel list? Could you create all the correct column names and types in SharePoint online and then the excel list imports correctly? This list was previously exported to excel from a SharePoint 2007 site. Could the change in column types occurred on the export?

Comment: How do you import the excel sheet?

Comment: Using import excel app